# Null value when retrieving value from combobox C#

Tags: c#, combobox, vpn, valuemember

This is supposed to get the value in a database attached via VPN. I have the query set to where it shows the title of the value in a dropdrown list and the system is supposed to get the valuemember of the selected value. Hence the valuemember in the field. It never finds a value, it just locks up. I know the VPN is active to access the database. Other than that I see no reason for the valuemember not to be transferring to the labelcode variable.

```
int labelcode = Convert.ToInt32(cmbboxLabel.ValueMember);
```

Comment: So which is it null, or locked up?

Comment: I use breakpoints and it shows the value is null. I have let it run and the program hasn't crashed.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I let it run for 5 minutes and it didn't crash. I was wondering if I took off the value member option and used selectedvalue will that fix my problem? I am using vs 2012 if it helps for reference.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was my while loop was continually executing.@TonyHopkinson

Comment: I meant more like when is it null. If cmbboxLabel.ValueMember is null, then either nothing is selected or the binding is wrong.

Comment: Ah well that would certainly make it look like it was locked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

int labelcode = Convert.ToInt32(cmbboxLabel.SelectedValue);

ValueMember is a string that tells the ComboBox which attribute of the bound object to give back with SelectedValue.

If your underlying class looked like this:

```
public class Example
{
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public int Value {get; set;}
}
```

Then you would set combobox.DisplayMember to "Title" and combobox.ValueMember to "Value".